# Big O Proof for Logarithmic Function

Tags: asymptotics, proof-techniques

I am an undergraduate student in Computer Engineering and going through one of the textbook examples, I am asked to prove that

$T(n)$ is $O(\log{}n)$

Where $T(n)= 5\log_{2} 2n +7$.
I understand that this means that I must prove that $5\log_{2} 2n +7 \leq\lambda log(n)$

For some in n in a neighborhood of infinity. How exactly would I proceed with this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Why did your approaches fail?

Comment: The thing is i dont understand how I am to begin

Comment: Looking into it, the professor and the book both describe ways of picking some arbitrary n>a and then building the inequality, eventually landing at some lambda value

Comment: possible duplicate: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/824/755

Answer (score 1):

$$5\log_2(2n)+7=5\log_2 n+5\log_2 2+7=5\log_2 n +12$$
Since for example $12\le 12\log_2 n$ for $n\ge 2$, it follows that
$$5\log_2 n +12\le 5\log_2 n +12\log_2 n=17\log_2 n $$
for $n\ge 2$. This yields $O(\log n) $.

Comment: While this answers the question, it is common usage to not answer a question until the OP has made a serious effort at solving it on their own and (in the case of such a basic question) showed their attempts and why they failed.

Comment: Sorry. I am sick and bored.. :)

Comment: @Danny [Here, take these](http://reitzig.github.io/research/open-questions/).